# При изменении разрешения экрана происходит вот так(фото). Как предотвратить?

Tags: css

[image: Это до]

[image: Это после]

Делал процентами, флоатом. Как то можно сделать, чтобы при уменьшении размера он не падал, а как бы overflow, scroll пошел и сайт не разрушался вот так?

Comment: Clearfix, Media Queries?

Comment: Обернуть кирпичики в контейнер конкретной ширины не получится?

Если бы картинки были в одну строку, то возможно вам помогло бы white-space: nowrap; для строки и display: inline-block; (вместо обтекания) для элементов. Но у вас две строки. Можете выводить блоки отдельными строками?

Comment: покажите код, у Вас это скорее всего реализовано через div ?

Comment: Экстрасенсы - собирайтесь все! Давайте гадать, что там и как. ^^ - причин может быть ой-ей-ей сколько :) от банального `inline-block` и до `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Контейнеру со списком изображения задайте фиксированную ширину.

Answer (score 0):

Дайте минимальную ширину элементам: `html`, `body`. Сколько у Вас занимают по ширине элементы? Дайте 1000 пикселей минимально или 1200.